# React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'reduxArray'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, eslint

I need to call useEffect when ever *data* changes like below,

```
 useEffect(()=>{
     const filteredData = reduxArray.filter(
       () => // do something
 );
     store.dispatch(method({reduxArray:[...filteredData]}))
  },[data])
```

this actually meets my requirement and works fine for me but Eslint is not happy with the same and gives me the error **React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'reduxArray'. Either include it or remove the dependency array**.

In that case if I add *reduxArray* in the dependency array then it causes infinite loop in the useEffect since I am updating *reduxArray* in the useEffect.
Is there a way other than disabling eslint to overcome this ?

Comment: I assume you filter reduxArray if some filter changes?

Instead of manipulating the state and just providing it with dispatch you can do something else.

If you move the redux state mutation logic into the reducer it would not complain. You filter based on something.

`store.dispatch( filterChanged(newFilterValues) );`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's a good solution are not but if you want to remove eslint warning then just use

```
  useEffect(()=>{
   const filteredData = reduxArray.filter(() => // do something);
   store.dispatch(method({reduxArray:[...filteredData]}))
   // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
  },[data])
```

Comment: This is what I've done for our projects eslint settings.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that I like for this is to use the useCallback in a function, this will prevent an infinite loop.

```
const handleChangeData = useCallback (() => {
    const filteredData = reduxArray.filter();
    store.dispatch(method({reduxArray:[...filteredData]}))
  },[data,reduxArray])

  useEffect(()=>{
    handleChangeData
 },[handleChangeData])
```

Comment: since reduxArray is added as a dependency inside useCallback it still gives me an infinite loop

Answer (score 0):

One solution to this problem is the `useEvent` hook:

```
  const filterData = useEvent(()=>{
    const filteredData = reduxArray.filter(
      () => // do something
);
    store.dispatch(method({reduxArray:[...filteredData]}))
  })

  useEffect(()=>{
    filterData()
 },[data])
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by simply keeping a flag right after updating the redux array, I am not sure if it is the right approach,

```
useEffect(()=>{
     const filteredData = reduxArray.filter(
       () => // do something
     );
if(!flag) {
     store.dispatch(method({reduxArray:[...filteredData]}))
 }
  setFlag(true); // so that it doesn't reupdate infinite times
  },[data])
```